# Mysql is not accessible via localhost

Tags: php, mysql, linux, xampp, lampp

I have installed Lampp in my computer which is running on OpenSuse 13.1. The problem is I am unable to access mysql from the hostname '**localhost**', but it can be accessed via hostnames '**localhost:3306**' or '**127.0.0.1**'. That's really strange! This has really messed up my project. Guys is there any way out to access mysql from the hostname localhost?
Thanks in advance!

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
fe00::0         ipv6-localnet
ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts

127.0.0.1 HOME-PC.home # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
127.0.0.1 HOME-PC # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
```

and my /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf file:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = /opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/
```

Comment: If you use `localhost` instead of an IP Address, then MySQL will try to connect over a socket instead of TCP/IP (which is more efficient and desirable). Something is presumably preventing it from finding the right socket. What errors is the client you are using reporting? Does `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` exist?

Comment: yeah /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock exists and when i try to run `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql` in the terminal, it throws `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)` while running `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1` it successfully gets connected! Should i try doing some port forwarding? if so could please guide me what to do? Thanks! :)

Comment: Port forwarding won't help. You aren't trying to access the server on a different network.

Comment: @Quentin any other work round?

Comment: I'd try to figure out why the socket isn't working instead of trying to work around it. Permissions problem maybe?

Comment: Ok! kindly let me know how to fix this permission problem! Or can you provide me any link which describes it!